# With Tkinter, how to make ttk.Button size fit to its text?

Tags: python, tkinter

I looked through the Button widget's options, but couldn't find anything that looks like "fit to content" there.

Do I have to set size explicitly in order to fit the button size to its `text`?

Example:

```
import tkinter as TK
from tkinter import ttk

root = TK.Tk()
root.title('Buttons bigger than text')
root.geometry('{}x{}+0+0'.format(800, 800))
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

mainFrame = TK.Frame(root, bg='green')
mainFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

for r in range(0, 5):
    row = TK.Frame(mainFrame, bg='blue')
    mainFrame.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
    mainFrame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    row.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    bt1 = ttk.Button(row, text='mybutton')
    bt2 = ttk.Button(row, text='?')
    row.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    row.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    row.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    bt1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsw')
    bt2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nsw')
root.mainloop()
```

Is it a ttk.Button specific issue? I tested with Tk.Button and it worked as expected.

**Environment**

Python 3.6.4 Homebrew on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: It should fit to its text by default. Please create a [mcve] that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks Bryan! I updated my question. It's actually the ttk button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, button widgets will try to fit their text. That is their documented behavior. You're explicitly asking for them to stretch to fill their space when you use the `sticky` option.

Also, on OSX specifically, I think there may be limitations in the minimum size of the button when using the native theme, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan! I removed the `sticky`, so at least I have the thinner buttons along its height, but can't seem to tweak its width at all. I guess this is just how ttk.Button works on macOS then. Another thing that works differently on Mac!